# Sort array with additional array exceptions

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have for example two arrays:

One with exceptions:

```
array('dog', 'cat', 'macbook')
```

And another with all values:

```
array('computer', 'mom', 'cat', 'dog')
```

I would like to get sorted array with following order:

```
array('dog', 'cat', 'computer', 'mom') // first with exception order and another elements alphabetically
```

How to do it?

Comment: usort allows a custom callback.

Comment: you don't want macbook to come in result array ?

Comment: Yes, I know but I have no idea how to solve problem with exceptions order, can you write some pseudo-code?

Comment: @VforVendetta, I'm sorting this array: array('computer', 'mom', 'cat', 'dog')

Comment: Okay, give me a sec, call me 'V' ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code

```
$exceptions =       array('dog', 'cat', 'macbook');
$main_arr =         array('computer', 'mom', 'cat', 'dog');
$temp = [];
$result_arr = [];
foreach($exceptions as $k => $v){
    if(in_array($v, $main_arr)){
        $result_arr[] = $v; // adding in result array which matches exceptions with main array
        unset($main_arr[array_search($v,$main_arr)]); // unsetting from main array with matches with exception array
    }
}
$main_arr = array_values(array_filter($main_arr)); // correcting indexing of main array

$result_arr = array_merge($result_arr, $main_arr);
print_r($result_arr);
```

You can write your custom code like this, anyway this code will work

Answer (score 1):

combine the difference and intersection as this:

```
<?php
$seq = array('dog', 'cat', 'macbook');
$data = array('computer', 'mom', 'cat', 'dog');
array_merge(array_intersect($seq, $data), array_diff($data, $seq));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code does combine exceptions that are contained within values (in the same order as in `$exceptions`) with values, that have exceptions excluded.

```
$exceptions = ['dog', 'cat', 'macbook'];
$values = ['computer', 'mom', 'cat', 'dog'];

sort($values);
$values = array_merge(
    array_intersect($exceptions, $values),
    array_diff($values, $exceptions)
);
```

I would not bother with `sort` operating on all values, unless you have a larger list of exceptions. Then, the solution might be rewritten as:

```
$exceptSlice = array_intersect($exceptions, $values);
$valuesSlice = array_diff($values, $exceptSlice);
sort($valuesSlice);
$values = array_merge($exceptSlice, $valuesSlice);
```